# SQL End Time as start Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Table containing data's as follows,

[image]

I want them to be seperated as Start Time and End time where the Start and end are same for first row while second row start time is first row End time.

Comment: Going forward,please paste data as text and not images.Also see this link to know more on how to ask a question :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Check out this link to see why images should not be posted:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(time, 1, time) over (order by time) as starttime,
       time as endtime
from t;
```

Comment: @SrinivasanRajasekaran Please accept this answer by clicking on the check mark to the left, under the vote count box. It lets other users know your problem has been solved.